# GWT on Tomcat 7 shows a single session

Tags: session, gwt, tomcat

I have deployed my first GWT application to the Tomcat 7 standalone server (not in Apache).
In the application, I am storing some information in the session using

```
getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().setAttribute(...)
```

The problem is that Tomcat is always showing a single session. That means that when I run this application from different browsers or even different computers (with different public IPs), I get the same session and the same attributes set by another user!

On the Tomcat manager, I see a single session only

Is this a normal behavior? Can this be changed to have a session for each actual session?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new session for each user

`getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true).setAttribute(...)`

you can check with session id.weather creating a new session or not by writing .

```
 HttpSession session = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true);
 System.out.println("Session id: " + session.getId());
```

Comment: This is what I am doing and I am getting the same session id!

Happens also in the development environment (Eclipse & jetty)

Comment: Another important comment: I am not using appengine and I don't have appengine-web.xml to enable sessions there

Comment: can you please explain the flow ?

Comment: Using the latest GWT 2.5.1 I can reproduce on the GWT demo application. Just create new application without checking AppEngine. Send a call from client to server and run this
 
HttpSession httpSession = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true);
Logger.getGlobal().info("Restore session, session id = " + httpSession.getId());


Run inside Eclipse and connect with two different browsers. I am getting the same session id in the console

Comment: Whats happening getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(false) getting null ??

Comment: I feel stupid. All browsers I was using were using synchronization with my account and were sharing cookies. Tries incognito mode and it is working

Comment: :). seems like you are storing sessionId as a cookie.